# error Unable to open sql file

Tags: oracle, batch-file

I am trying to execute a batch file from windows task scheduler . After opening command prompt  it showing error unable to open SQL file. but when i am trying to run batch file by double clicking it is running smoothly and updating the database properly .

code used -->  `Sqlplus -s %userid%/%password%@%database% @"abc.sql"`

Comment: maybe you need either `cd /path/to/sql/code ; sqlplus ...` OR `Sqlplus -s ... @"/path/to/sql/abc.sql"`? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking access rights for the SQL file

Comment: On double clicking the batch file . It is running properly without error. error is coming only when i am trying to run Batch file by task scheduler .

Comment: try using full file path in the script